# How to include css file in php for hiding the folder structure?

Tags: php, css

top.php

```
$smarty->assign('style_url',STORE_URL.'csscon.php?store='.STORE_ID);
$smarty->display(PATH.'top.tpl');
```

top.tpl

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{$style_url}">
```

csscon.php

```
include PATH.'css/'.STORE_ID.'/css/style.css';
```

If see the view source code, it shows all the CSS styles, but it's not applying the CSS. So how can I apply this style?

Thanks

Comment: If you see the css in view source then click on the file and see if you get 404 (or check your console for 404) Maybe the path is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

if you put a blank page called index.html in the css folder, it won't show the directory structure if someone goes to http://url/css/.

Comment: this is not what he's asking. The styles are not applied

Comment: I admit I was a bit confused at what he was trying to do. I thought he was just trying to hide the folder structure.